# Is there a list of relesed updates for Ubuntu?

Tags: updates

Does Canonical publishes list of released updates or exists other way to verify is an update not a fake? I can't find anything on the web.

Comment: All updates are signed. They are not fake.

Comment: Such a "list" would run to many thousands (tens of thousands on LTS releases). All packages (including updated packages) are signed, and apt automatically verifies the signature before installing the updated package. If you [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1317732/edit) to be a bit more specific about your concern, we can be a bit more specific in our responses.

Comment: You can see the changes with `apt changelog` followed by the package name.

Comment: After typing `apt changelog` i get this message: `E: Handler silently failed`.